# 森 vs 林 for forest

Tags: word-choice, kanji, definitions

According to *A Guide to Remembering Japanese Characters*, 森 (38) is woods and 林 (75) is forest.

But some material I've found online related to Japan seems to indicate 森 is the more correct Japanese word for forest.

Is the book correct or do native Japanese speakers use 森 for forest, and not 林?

**Edit**: To give a little more context I originally avoided in the question to avoid appearing commercial but now I see will help make answers more specific, one of these words is already used to brand a product. If it's the incorrect word I'll need to change the product name.

I hope that helps, and I apologize if being vague hampers you giving what you feel is an appropriate response.

Comment: Well, both the kanji look like trees anyway :D

Answer (score 7):

林 is usually used for "copse", and 森 for "forest".

Comment: Do you mean "corpse"?

Comment: [Nope.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/copse)

Comment: I'd say "woods"... "copse" is an exceedingly rare word.

Comment: @Kef, indeed. Especially if the trees aren't periodically cut and since this isn't the English Language and Usage Q&A site.

Comment: I used the word "grove" the other day for 林

Comment: That would be a simple-yet-good answer if you changed it to "woods" or "grove". The word "copse" is just too rare and confusing.

Comment: I had never heard the word "copse" until I was studying the kanji. I'm not sure enough about the etymology to present this as it's own answer, but instead of thinking direct translation, I think it's fair to simply consider 森 the larger body of wooded area than 林.

Comment: +1 for using the wonderful word "copse"

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit late but hopefully it will be useful to others. I was just discussing this question with a native Japanese speaker (who is also a language teacher). Here's what he said:

- 林 (はやし): A small collection of trees. A small wood, a copse or a bunch of bushes.
- 森 (もり): A large wood/a small forest. This one is also meant to conjure up images of bigger, denser, deep green trees as opposed to small trees with light foliage.

...so generally speaking, 森 > 林.

- 森林 (しんりん): Put them both together and this means a big forest, like the type that would cover a mountain in Japan. This is what the English word 'forest' would usually be translated to.

Answer (score 4):

It's going to depend on the type of place you're describing. In the case of 森、which in goo's dictionary leads to 森林:

> 樹木、特に高木が群生して大きな面積を占めている所。また、その植物群落

Loose translation: "A place where trees and shrubs, more specifically tall trees occupy a large area in mass"

Source: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/115966/m0u/

Where in the case of 林:

> 樹木がたくさん集まって生えている所

Source: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/179447/m0u/%E6%9E%97/

Loose Translation: "A place where trees and shrubs gather and grow"

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like I might need to write a follow-up question.

Answer (score 3):

Put them together. 森林 (しんりん）

For example: アメリカ合衆国国立森林公園 American National Forest Park

[This Japanese Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E6%A3%AE%E6%9E%97%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7) will give you a huge list of examples using: 森, 林, 森林, and others like 梅林. But it seems like "nani nani no mori" is very commonly used. "Nani nani no hayashi" seems not to be used.

Comment: 森林 is used when you're talking about tree areas in general. 森 and 林 are more specific, with the former referring to denser groups of trees (i.e. forests), and 林 referring to "copse" as Ignacio notes.